# How to get the difference between two dates with 360 days/year, 30 days/month format?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, diff

I can get the difference between two dates (DD/MM/YY format) with the following code;

```
$date1   = new DateTime("1986-04-27");
$today  = new DateTime("now");
$interval   = $date1->diff($today);
$year       = $interval->format('%y');
$month      = $interval->format('%m');
$day        = $interval->format('%d');
```

It works perfect when calculating 1 year 2 months but when I'm trying to calculate 1 year 2 months 3 days, it doesn't give me the accurate result.

I would like to get the difference between two dates, using 360 days for a year, 30 days for a month, without calculating leap years..

For example; if a month has 31 days the system will calculate it as 30 days.
If a year has 365 days, the system will calculate it as 1 year 5 days. (360 + 5)

How can I do that?

Thank you..

Comment: I don't really understand what (and why) you want to achieve but I think transferring the dates into days should be the starting point. Then you just devide by 360 or 30, ...

Comment: So when there are 8 real years between the two, you want to get 8 years and 1 month and 10 days? Seems really odd...

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to make this calculation in that way is because I'm working on a project which I can calculate retirement age. Our goverment calculates 360 days for a year, 30 days for a month. I don't know why..  @Jeff

Comment: Well, then I think you described it wrong in your question. An actual year of 365 days is then not 1 year + 5 days, but a year of 360 days, completely omitting the 5 days (not adding them or counting them in any way).

Comment: I would like to say that if a year has 365 days, the system will calculate it 360 days (a year) and 5 days ..  @trincot

Comment: Well, that I have done in my answer, but I doubt that is the way pensions are calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

```
function diff360($date1, $date2) {
    $date1 = new DateTime($date1);
    $date2 = new DateTime($date2);
    $diff = $date1->diff($date2);
    $days = ($date2->format('d') + 30 - $date1->format('d')) % 30;
    return array(
        "y" => $diff->y,
        "m" => $diff->m,
        "d" => $days,
        "totaldays" => $diff->y * 360 + $diff->m * 30 + $days
    );
}

$result = diff360("2016-02-06", "2016-03-06");
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'y' => 0,
  'm' => 1,
  'd' => 0,
  'totaldays' => 30,
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but if you will calculate this with the today's date (2016-02-06), you will see the result as 29. I don't want to make this calculation with calendar format.

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't know what you mean? I don't get 29 with dates set to 1986-04-27 and 2016-02-06. The output of the above code is 30 2 17 for these dates. That means that between those days you can fit 30 years of 360 days, and 2 months of 30 days and 17 days. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Can you please try this code ? [link] (http://pastebin.com/L5EHyF4W)

It will give you 29 days because it is calculating the date with calendar format but I don't want to get the result with calendar format. I want to calculate 30 days for a month (not 29 or 31) and 360 for a month (not 365)

Comment: But that is not my code... My code does not follow calendar format.

Comment: Ok, I tried your code and it gives me 29 (0 0 29) as well.. Here's the link : http://pastebin.com/4TNaGxdU  

I want to get it as 0 1 0

Comment: I updated my answer to what you are explaining: a year is a year, a month is a month, but day differences should be calculated as if a month is 30 days and a year 360 days. Please check if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you @trincot . This is what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Just get the number of days and substract the years / months.

```
$totalDays = $interval->format('%a');
$years = 0;
$months = 0;
while ($totaldays >= 360) { $years++; $totaldays -=360; }
while ($totaldays >= 30) { $months++; $totaldays -=30; }
$days = $totalDays
```

But why do you need a broken date format?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote this following code;

$date1   = new DateTime("2016-02-06");
    $today  = new DateTime("now");
    $interval   = $date1->diff($today);
    $year       = $interval->format('%y');
    $month      = $interval->format('%m');
    $day        = $interval->format('%d');
    $totalDays  = $interval->format('%a');

    echo $totalDays;

and the result is 29 days because February has 29 days this year but I want to do this calculation with 30 days for a month. I want to calculate months with 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime class will calculate a difference based on real dates. It's kind of random whether it will work or not in your example. If you want to use custom lengths for months, ignore leap years etc. then you will have to create custom functions yourself.

I don't really understand the point of doing this though?

Comment: Hi, I couldn't create custom functions myself, that's why I'm asking :) 

I'm working on a project right now and this project is using this kind of date format.