# Difference between two dates with 360 days/year, 30 days/month format in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, diff

I want to ask a question regarding the answer given in this post ([How to get the difference between two dates with 360 days/year, 30 days/month format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832487/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-with-360-days-year-30-days-month-fo)) which i can't comment because i don't have the necessary reputation.
The provided function

```
function diff360($date1, $date2) {
    $date1 = new DateTime($date1);
    $date2 = new DateTime($date2);
    $diff = $date1->diff($date2);
    $days = ($date2->format('d') + 30 - $date1->format('d')) % 30;
    return array(
        "y" => $diff->y,
        "m" => $diff->m,
        "d" => $days,
        "totaldays" => $diff->y * 360 + $diff->m * 30 + $days
    );
}
```

generally works well except for certain cases e.g. `diff360("2020-09-01", "2021-07-01");` where it outputs "0 years,9 months,0 days", instead of the desired "0 years, 10 months, 0 days".
Can you please explain why?

Comment: On which OS did you run this code?

Comment: I can't reproduce that for the latest versions of PHP 7.3, 7.4, 8.0, 8.1, and 8.2. Can you share more details about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem stems from my default timezone (i don't know why) which is European. if i change the timezone to America e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Even when i change the timezone, for years where February has 28 days and for cases like diff360("2010-01-30","2010-03-01"), the above code outputs $totaldays = 1, which is incorrect. I wrote the code below, which does not depend in php's date functions, to emulate excel's DAYS360 function for anyone interested,

```
    //inputs 2 dates yyyy-mm-dd (start,finish) outputs total diff days+1 
    public function Diff360($arxi, $telos) {
    //i consider all months to have 30 days
     if(substr($arxi,8,2) == 31){
        $arxi = substr($arxi,0,8) . "30";
     }
     if(substr($telos,8,2) == 31){
       $telos = substr($telos,0,8) . "30";
     }
     $arxi_d = explode("-",$arxi);
     $telos_d = explode("-",$telos);
     $totaldays = 0;
     if( $telos_d[0] == $arxi_d[0]  ){
      if($telos_d[1] == $arxi_d[1]){
        return  $telos_d[2] - $arxi_d[2] + 1;
      }
      $totaldays += 30 - $arxi_d[2] + 1;
      $yp_minas = $arxi_d[1] + 1;
      $totaldays += ($telos_d[1] - $yp_minas) *30;
      $totaldays += $telos_d[2];
      return $totaldays;
    }
    if( $telos_d[0] - $arxi_d[0] > 1 ){
     $totaldays += 360 * ( $telos_d[0] - $arxi_d[0] - 1 );
    }
    $totaldays += 30 - $arxi_d[2] + 1;
    $yp_minas = $arxi_d[1] + 1;
    if( $yp_minas <= 12 ){
     $totaldays += ( 13 - $yp_minas ) * 30;
    }
    $totaldays += ($telos_d[1] - 1) * 30;
    $totaldays += $telos_d[2];
    return $totaldays;
  }
```